# Increase left margin in MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to increase the left margin by -190px with each click a maximum of 6 times. I currently have

```
$$('#goright').addEvent('click', function(){
     $$('#buttons').tween('marginLeft', -190);
})
```

But this only fires once. I need to run on every click (jQuery would use something like ++) and then only to a maximum of 6 times (I assume this would also use something like < 6).

Any help???

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.  Basically create a global var count and increment it every time by 1.  On click even basically check to see if click is less than 6 and if it is grab all the buttons and do an each loop on them and then tween them individually.  The trick is to get the current el's margin-left style and then convert it to int in order to drop the `px` and then add or subtract depends on where you want the element's `margin-left` to go.  Here is the [***JSFIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/wC5Xk/) demoing it in action, but instead of going -190 i went with +10 so you can see the effect.  Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.  By the way this is using Mootools core 1.3 fully compatible:

```
var count = 0;

$('goright').addEvent('click', function(){
    if(count < 6){
         $$('.btn').each(function(el){
             el.tween('margin-left', el.getStyle('margin-left').toInt()-190);
         });
    }
    count++;
});
```

HTML i used:

```
<button class='btn'>1</button>
<button class='btn'>2</button>
<button class='btn'>3</button>
<button class='btn'>4</button>

<div id='goright'>Click To Go Right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny thing to do, actually! If you can use MooTools More, there's the possibility to define pseudo events. Events, that "do something" with themselves after executing. So insted of `myEl.addEvent('click', fn)` you would use `myEl.addEvent('click:once', fn)`. In MooTools, `:once` is defined, it fires once, then deattaces, that means, after a second click on `myEl`, nothing will happen (the EventListener has deatached).

I've created a `:times(n)` pseudo event, no big deal, but it makes clear how to use these so-called pseudos. Here is a [link to it](http://jsfiddle.net/bc7FR/).

Maybe this can help you or someone else.

Cheers and happy coding!